# How to configure alerts for employee contract expiration in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

How do i configure the system to email me when an employees contract is going to expire? For example I need to get an email 30 days before the expiration.  i tried to  create an automated action following some tutorial but i don't find the filed  Timer Trigger Date and  Delay After Trigger Date in odoo 8 any help please ?

Comment: better to try corn job

Comment: i don't get you

Answer (score 0):

hr_contract model have end date_end based on that write corn job or what ever you want